# Check if object inherits from generic class or arbitrary set of classes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I have a mutable set of classes - or better class types - and want to check that a random object - directly or indirectly - inherits any of these classes.

I've written a small Playground Test for direct inheritance check using `===` and indirect check using `is` or `as?`:

```
import Foundation

protocol Product {init()}

class LowGradeProduct: Product {required init() {}}
class HighGradeProduct: Product {required init() {}}

class A: LowGradeProduct {}
class B: HighGradeProduct {}
class ExtraFancyB: B {}
class C: HighGradeProduct {}
class RandomClass {}

class SnobjectChecker {
    var allowedClass: [HighGradeProduct.Type] = []

    func addCls( cls: HighGradeProduct.Type ) {
        allowedClass.append(cls)
    }

    func checkCls( obj: AnyObject ) -> Bool {
        for allowedCls in allowedClass {

            /* 1. check object class equality, works */
            if type(of: obj) as AnyClass === allowedCls as AnyClass {
                return true
            }

            /* 2. check object class heritance via upcast: not working */
            if let _ = obj as? allowedCls {
                return true
            }


            /* 3. check object class heritance via is: not working  */
            if obj is allowedCls {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}

let fac = SnobjectChecker.init()

fac.addCls(cls: B.self)

for cls in [A.self, B.self, C.self, ExtraFancyB.self] as! [Product.Type] {
    print("object of \(cls) is allowed: \(fac.checkCls(obj: cls.init() as AnyObject))")
}
print("object of \(RandomClass.self) is allowed: \(fac.checkCls(obj: RandomClass.init() as AnyObject))")
```

The check of class equality works but it misses indirect inheritance like `ExtraFancyB`.

Neither `is` nor the upcast `as?` do work, it seems they both only allow static Types since the compiler complains about a missing type `allowedCls`.

Is there another way to check if an object inherits from a random set of classes to accomplish this with swift 2.3/3+ and if possible without some hacks like classname comparison?

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but `if (type(of: obj) as AnyClass).isSubclass(of: allowedCls)`?

Comment: Ah I see, that `isSubclass` method does work. Would you like to make that an Answer?

Comment: @Larme Probably worth noting that you can only use that method on an Apple platform where you have access to the Obj-C runtime. [It wouldn't work for example on Linux](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/592d9d83ed0d454b0b7c5de9).

Comment: @Hamish Good point, still forget the Swift multiplatform version that seems more encouraging than the Objective-C one.

Comment: @Hamish Interesting. Maybe I should add an Apple/iOS tag. My real world problem is based on some `AVFoundation` classes, so its actually solved with that. In pure swift this may be a much to hard problem..

Comment: @makadev Yeah, I don't *believe* it's possible to do in 'pure Swift' – at least not without relying on undocumented features. Really it's a shame there aren't more powerful language features/stdlib APIs for working with metatypes.